# Как обрезать файл на n байт, начиная сначала?

Tags: c++, qt, файлы, qt5, файловая-система

В Qt есть метод `QFile::resize(bt)`, который устанавливает размер файла на bt, обрезая всё что идёт дальше. 
Есть ли аналог (и вообще, "законно" ли так делать), который урезает файл на bt, начиная сначала?

**Контекст задачи:** есть вообще сторонний процесс, который кладёт логи в файл *file*, поэтому синхронизироваться по доступу к файлу не получится. При поступлении записей мне file надо читать, парсить все, что туда записано, и обрезать считанные данные (пишутся в другой файл). 
Конечно же это требуется делать синхронно, дабы ничего не потерять. Я пока додумался только до варианта, озвученного выше.

Comment: Подумайте о последнем тайстемпе изменения и предыдущей позиции в файле.

Comment: а зачем необходимо обрезать считанные данные?

Comment: @goldstar_labs чтобы при перезапуске моей программы парсить только то из файла, что еще не трогал, и добавлять в свой файл. Файл, заполняемый сторонним процессом, ротируется ежедневно

Comment: [truncate(2) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/truncate)

Comment: @avp как эти функции коррелируют с задачей усечения с начала?

Comment: @magrif, ага, неверно понял вопрос. Вам надо срезать голову, а не хвост. Тогда посмотрите на [fallocate](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fallocate.2.html) (особенно на раздел `Collapsing file space`)

Answer (score 0):

С помощью любых resize нельзя, так как будут удалены данные от конца к началу. Для удаления данных от начала к концу, вы можете воспользоватся методом установки позиции QFile::seek(qint64). После чего прочитать и скопировать данные в файл.